# Nginx Timeout 20s Causes 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx

Weird bug/error/feature. In my nginx config, I have my timeouts set really low, as such:

```
proxy_connect_timeout       20s;
proxy_send_timeout          20s;
proxy_read_timeout          20s;
send_timeout                20s;
reset_timedout_connection on;
```

There is a weird occurence. Right now the timeout is at 20s, and if go the website, ie: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), it will sometimes connect, or it will sometimes give 502 Bad Gateway error.50/50 chance. But if I raise it to 60s, it works perfectly fine.

Any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

`20s` for `proxy_connect_timeout` isn't really low - I'd suggest that it's very high. This is the time it takes for nginx to just open a socket or port to the proxy (ie. the initial connection not for the proxy to respond). For instance, I've got `100ms` set in one of my configs.

I'll annotate your setup as these are often cargo-cult pasted from other places:

```
proxy_connect_timeout       20s; # time to open a connection to the proxy before we give up
proxy_send_timeout          20s; # timeout for transmitting a request to the proxied server
proxy_read_timeout          20s; # timeout for reading a response from the proxied server - did it send back anything before this has expired
send_timeout                20s; # timeout for sending a response to the requesting client - note this isn't proxy_send_timeout, but the time between two successive write operations to the requesting client (ie. browser)
reset_timedout_connection on;
```

When you say you change the timeout to `60s` - I presume you do it for all the `20s` values?

The most likely explanation is that your proxy is slow to respond - e.g. it must do a slow database query or request data from a slow API, or run some terrible php code, in which case the only timeout value you need to change is the `proxy_read_timeout`. You'll need to investigate why the code on the other end of the poxy is slow to respond.

The other potential point of failure is `proxy_connect_timeout`, but this would indicate that you're running a non-daemonised process or very slow CGI that takes over 20s *just to start up*, before it can even begin to process the nginx request.